# setting jQuery value into "items" attribute of <c:forEach>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to replace the "items" attribute value of **c:forEach** tag, with the jQuery value I got from below.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"tour_list_json?"+$.param(ratingJSON),
    async:true,
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
    success:function(jsonObject) {
        $('c\\:forEach:first').attr('items', jsonObject);
    }
});
```

Below is the tag I'm trying to make a change.

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${productList}">
```

Here I want **items="${productList}"** to become **items="jsonObject"**
so the  tag only prints out the newly obtained list of products.

As you can see,  I tried with
**$('c\:forEach:first').attr('items', jsonObject);**
but it doesn't change the result and I still see the original list of products. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use like `$('c\\:forEach:first').attr('items', jsonObject);` since you are using `JSP` you set `productList` in your `ModelMap`

```
   model.put("productList",productList);
```

And in your `jsps` just use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllProducts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List getAllProducts(ModelMap model) {
    ArrayList<Product> productList=new ArrayList<E>();
    //productList  add values
    return productList;
}

 success:function(jsonObject) {
     $(jsonObject).each(function(product){
       let productHTML = `<p>Product ${product.name}  Price ${product.price}`;
       $("#yourProductListEl").append(productHTML);
     })
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I already did as you said, but it is to show every single product when I first open the webpage.  What I'm trying to do is, when I give certain search condition as an input (ex. price range of $100~200), I want the webpage to show only products between $100 and $200.  Depending on the search condition, the "jsonObject" will return different list of products, and I wonder how I can reflect that on the webpage using ajax.